# Basic for loop issues with user data

Tags: python, for-loop

My goal is to create a plot of temperature (Te) as a function of solar constant (S0), ranging from 500 to 3000.  Use planetary albedo values of (αp) of 0.16 (Mars), 0.29 (Earth), and 0.71 (Venus).

I am trying to use a for loop to plug in my solar constants (ranging from 500 to 3000) and save the values to `Te` so I can plot. But am having issues running my for loop.

```py
# Plot Planetary emission temperature as a function of solar constant
# ranging from 500 to 3000 W m^-2
# Define known variables

index = 'Mars'; # user-input planet name

sigma = 5.67 * 10**-8;
solar_flux = np.arange(500,3001,1);
df = pd.DataFrame({'planet_albedo': [0.16, 0.29, 0.71]}, 
                  index=['Mars', 'Earth', 'Venus'])


save_temp_e = []; # empty list to append values to

for i in range(len(solar_flux)): 
    Temp_e = np.array(((solar_flux[i]/(sigma*4))(1-df.planet_albedo[index]))/sigma)**(1/4);
    save_temp_e.append(Temp_e)
```

I keep getting errors such as:

> TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable.

Comment: What exact line is the error coming from? On that line, if you add a breakpoint, what is the value and type of `solar_flux`?

Comment: While you can use semicolons to separate multiple codes on one line, ending each line with one is not necessary in Python. Doing away with those will make your code more readable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried your code and I got an error `'numpy.float64' object is not callable`.

Your formula is not correct, you miss probably a `*` sign here:

```
Temp_e = np.array(((solar_flux[i]/(sigma*4)) * (1-df.planet_albedo[index]))/sigma)**(1/4)
```

Comment: Ah-ha! I caught on to that. Thank you!